# Return all documents from Cloudant db through nodeJs

Tags: node.js, cloudant

Passing null or an empty Json to the selector does not seem to work.
I am trying to get all the data in a database.
Tried:

```
 db.list({}, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log("Error:",err.message);
        }
        console.log(data);
    });
    db.find(null, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log("Error:",err.message);
        }
        console.log(data);
    });
    db.bulk({docs:[]}, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log("Error:",err.message);
        }
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a list of all the documents, don't pass anything at all e.g.

```
db.list(function (err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});
```

If you want the document bodies too, then pass in `include_docs=true`:

```
db.list({include_docs:true}, function (err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});
```

This mirrors the CouchDB API for the `GET /db/_all_docs` endpoint - without any parameters, you get all the document ids and revision tokens.